# Insert/Update multiple lookup values to an SPListItem

Tags: c#, sharepoint, splistitem, spfieldcollection

My SharePoint list has a column that allows multiple lookup values.  My C# control (within a webpart) allows the user to make multiple selections from a list box.  I split these values into an array - each array member being a selected value that needs to be updated in the same SPListItem column.

I know that the selections are being passed in properly from the list box - I just need to add this group of values to the same column in the SPListItem.

Where am I going wrong?

```
SPFieldLookupValueCollection MyCollection = new SPFieldLookupValueCollection();
for (int i = 0; i < MyArrayOfSelections.Length; i++)
{
   if (MyLookupList["LookupColumn"].ToString() == MyArrayOfSelections[i].ToString())
   {
      MyID = int.Parse(MyLookupList[i]["ID"].ToString());
      SPFieldLookupValue thisSelection = new SPFieldLookupValue(MyID,MyArrayOfSelections[i].ToString());
      MySubCollection.Add(thisSelection);
      }
   }
   ListIWantToUpdate["ColumnWithMultipleLookupSelections"] = SubCollection;
   ListIWantToUpdate.Update();
   site.Update();
}
```

Comment: the code above is actually contained inside another for loop that loops through the SPListItemCollection from the lookup-list

Comment: Bah!  I found the problem - it was a silly one too.  On the outer for loop, i++...on the inner for loop j++.  When I looped through the array of selections from the listbox - I used the 'i' index instead of the 'j' index.  D'oh! 

I appreciate your site -- usually when I run into a snag...I can find the answer here.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The last rows of the code example are confusing (maybe it's just variable naming). If you are just updating the *data*, you never need to update neither the `SPList` object (this requires "Manage lists" permission on the particular list, nor `SPSite` ojbect (requires you to be site administrator or owner). So, this code will not run succcessfuly for a regular user.

Comment: I don't know how I missed the email notification when you answered!  Just ran across this today; I appreciate your response very much.  

Re: the confusing naming condition, mea culpa. I am updating a listItem.  Thank you for the correction on the SPSite object.  Your post was helpful.